# ANOSIM Error Vegan Package R - "Error in if (xi > xj) 1L else -1L : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Tags: r, statistics, vegan

I am trying to complete ANOSIM on species presence data with two grouping variables
Here is an example of the dataframe (the original dataframe has 50 columns):

```
print(rec.ano.wide[1:5])
# Groups:   cyclone_time [2]
  cyclone_time  acanthastrea acropora astreopora blastomussa
  <fct>               <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
1 before                 15      119         21           3
2 after                  10      154          6           1
```

I perform anosim analysis using this code :

```
#get the grouping variable
group <- rec.ano.wide[, "cyclone_time"]

#create community matrix
rec.com <- rec.ano.wide[,2:ncol(rec.ano.wide)]
rec.matrix = as.matrix(rec.com)

#anosim analysis
rec.ano = anosim(rec.matrix, group, distance = "bray", permutations = 9999)
```

That analysis gives this error

```
Error in if (xi > xj) 1L else -1L : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(xi, xj) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
```

I have no idea what this means so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Error message suggests that you have missing values in your community matrix. However, neither the error message nor the warning come from `anosim()`, but some other functions (called by `anosim`, or from functions called before `anosim`?). Does `sum(rec.matrix)` give a numerical result?

Comment: @JariOksanen Hi thank you for your comment - yes it did give a numerical result   `> sum(rec.matrix) [1] 1984`

Comment: Then there must be something fishy in `group`. After getting the error, say `traceback()`. This will show you where the error occurred (it did not occur in `anosim` that does not have anything that could give that error message: there is no `if (xi > xj)` in `anosim`).

Comment: You have *not* given the `traceback()`, and I must be guessing. Looking at the **R** source code, the error message comes from `rank()` for the dissimilarities. The message is clear: you have missing values in your dissimilarities (error), and your dissimilarities have factors (warning). That is what the computer says, and I never argue with the computer (I know I'll lose), but I'll bend down and check my data.